# A mysterious view is appearing/disappearing during a screen refresh

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

I'm in XCode 6.1.1 and iOS 8.x

As pictured, I have a map, and a tableview that shows details about a particular property on the map.  There is also a toolbar along the top (blurred) that has up/down arrows on it to move to the next property, which basically rebuilds the tableview and refreshes the screen.

Well notice the weird square that's about 1.5" x 1.5" in the center of the screen.
That square quickly appears and disappears in the center of the screen when the screen is refreshed moving from property to property.

I have no idea where that view is coming from.

Is there an instrument in Instruments to catch this view in the act so I can figure out what it is and where it's coming from.

I've used the Time Profiler, but I don't recognize anything in the backtraces that helps me figure out where this mystery view is coming from, and I don't believe it's being created by any of the code in my app, which makes it more troublesome.

If this was your app, how would you figure out where this mystery view is coming from?

[image]

Comment: Did you try setting up some break points?

Comment: I wouldn't have a clue what to break on because as far as I know, I'm not the one creating this mystery view that's appearing.  I don't know where it's coming from.  Also, a breakpoints are really ineffective with debugging view problems live because the view is not refreshing while you're stepping through code... that what instruments is for.

Comment: You need to upload a video or so at least.

Comment: It won't be quick and easy, but I'll try to do that tomorrow I guess.

Comment: It seems like a loading view with missing assets

Comment: if you are using or creating any View in background threads . This type of flickering will appear. check you code for these kinds if threads

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer within an Instruments time profile backtrace... turned out there was a third party activity indicator buried deep in some code.
Dooh!!

Instruments to the rescue once again.